# What is fastApi analog for the flask request.environ.get('HTTP_REFERER', "")?

Tags: python, fastapi, http-referer

So I want to get current request `'HTTP_REFERER'`. In Flask it is in `request.environ.get('HTTP_REFERER', "")`. How to get one in fastapi?

Answer (score 3):

`HTTP_REFERER` [is just a request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer), which you can access in a FastAPI endpoint using the `referer` key as follows:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/foo")
def foo(request: Request):
    http_referer = request.headers.get('referer')
    return {"http_referer": http_referer}
```

More information located in the [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/).

Comment: In FastAPI you don't use the HTTP_ prefix. Use: request.headers.get("Referer").

Comment: Much cleaner to use `referer: Annotated[str | None, Header()]`